# Make GCP Function Public - IAM policy update failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I have GCP throwing me an IAM Error when trying to make a function totally 100% public.

Under Permissions, in the function: Add > New Members: allUsers > Role: Essential Contact Viewer.
It warns you about making it fully public to all on the Internet (this is what I want)
[Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJV7Y.png)

However, when clicking "Allow Public Access" it throws an error.

Note: I've tried this on my local machine and same error & also occurs when I try it on "allAuthenticatedUsers".

I cannot search the error ID as a unique one is produced any time an attempt is made.

Is there a step I've missed or is this a GCP problem?

[Prompt verifying Admin wants GCP Function fully Public
[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe5DS.png)

Edit: Added images

Comment: Try the role: Cloud Functions Invoker

Comment: "No change - member already exists on the policy." Which I do remember doing, but still no luck. Setup a new Project, function (ensuring Allow Unauthentication) too :(

Comment: So, if all users have cloud functions invoker role, anyone can access them! What's the problem??

Comment: Idk :( Same issues, tried again today. Definitely smth to do with GCP. Will keep posted if when there's an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Needed to "Enable the APIs", then select your Project name that your function resides in. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart#functions_quickstart_helloworld-python